# PHP Handle json sent POST and rewrite existing json with the new one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to update json file on the server on button click. 
 So when i click the button `#update` I'm collecting values from input fields and insert them to json object then I sent this json object to controller.php.
But how to handle this json object delete the old json file and and create new json file with the json object in it.

Lets say the json file path is : js/currencies.json

JS:

```
function ajaxPost(obj){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "controller.php",
                data: {myData:obj},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    alert('Items added');
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){       
                $('#update').on('click', function(){
                    var objrates = 
                    {
                        "EURbuy" : $('#eurbuy').val(),
                        "EURsell" : $('#eursell').val(),
                        "USDbuy" : $('#usdbuy').val(),
                        "USDbuy" : $('#usdbuy').val()
                    }
                    ajaxPost(objrates);
                });                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            });
```

PHP :

```
    <?php   
    $data[] = $_POST['myData'];
    $inp = file_get_contents('js/currencies.json');
    $tempArray = json_decode($inp);
    array_push($tempArray, $data);
    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
    file_put_contents('js/currencies.json', $jsonData);
?>
```

The php code works withouth errors but the .json file is not replaced with the new values

Comment: You can directly write this to the location on server using [file_put_contents][1] :

    <?php
    $obj = $_POST['myData'];
    file_put_contents("path/js/currencies.json", $obj);
    ?>


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: so something like this ?
file_put_contents("js/currencies.json",$obj);   ?

Comment: what value does your $json variable have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_encode to return the altered object or save it to a file with [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php 
    $obj = $_POST['myData'];
    $obj['key'] = 'newVal';//edith the values based on key
    echo $json = json_encode(array('newobj'=>$obj));//echo the json object if you want
     file_put_contents('js/currencies.json',$json); //replace the json with new json in the file
?>
```

Note: you can even pass the file name to the ajax and retrieve to to append the it
alter the data:

```
data: {myData:obj,filename:'js/currencies.json'},
```

php get the url and alter the file:

```
$filename= $_POST['filename'];
file_put_contents($filename,$json);
```

Comment: ok but i dont see the file path to the old .json file are you missing something

Comment: can you explain what each line does im really new to php 

I dont get what 'key' does in this situation i want to replace the whole .json file with the new json passed from ajax

Comment: then you remove `$obj['key'] = 'newVal';` if you don't edit the json on the server

Comment: i want to edit the json on the server without returning something
the php code must just replace the .json file on the server with the new .json passsd from the client-side i dont need to return something to the client

Comment: then you remove the echo and you update with `$obj['key'] = 'newVal';`

Comment: can you update your answer so i see the full picture

Comment: what picture,i don't have any picture in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109235/discussion-between-georgi-antonov-and-madalin-ivascu).

Comment: everything works i dont get errors but the .json file is not updated with the new values instead it is erased see my edit that i tested